# What defines those OpenGL render dimension limits?

Tags: opengl

On my system, anything I draw with OpenGL outside of the range of around (-32700,32700) is not rendered (or folded back into the range, I can't figure out).

What defines those limits? Can they be modified?

---

Edit: Thanks all for pointing the right direction. It turned out my drawing code was using GLshort values. I replaced those by GLint values and I don't see those limits anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you are doing, but this looks like a numeric overflow of a signed 16-bit integer (-32768..32767).

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling `glVertex3s` to draw your vertices? As Malte Clasen pointed out, your vertices would overflow at 2^15-1.